# Macro that takes number of lines and outputs blank lines for writing derivation

Tags: macros, amsmath, loops, pgffor

I would like to output n lines of the form "= ......". On each line the student has to write one step of the derivation. I managed to make it working for 3 lines but my macro for n lines doesn't work.

My minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\mystrut}{\rule[-0.05\baselineskip]{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}}
\newcommand*{\mybox}[1]{\framebox{\mystrut #1}}
\newcommand{\derivblank}[1]{
    \begin{align*}
    \foreach \line in {1, ..., #1}{%
        &= \hspace{0.2cm}\underline{\mystrut\hspace{3cm}}  \\
    }
    &=  \hspace{0.2cm}  \mybox{\underline{ \hspace{3cm}}}
    \end{align*}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Derivation of 3 steps}
    Write your derivation below in 3 steps:
    \begin{align*}
    &= \hspace{0.2cm}\underline{\mystrut\hspace{3cm}}  \\
    &= \hspace{0.2cm}\underline{\mystrut\hspace{3cm}} \\
    &=  \hspace{0.2cm}  \mybox{\underline{ \hspace{3cm}}}
    \end{align*}
    
    \section*{Fails for arbitrary number of lines}
    Write your derivation below in $n$ steps:
    %\derivblank{2}
\end{document}
```

When uncommenting \derivblank, the second section is not rendered and I get a lot of syntax errors but I can't see where they come from?[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cell of an alignment is a local group, and you start the pgf loop in one cell so as soon as it inserts `&` the scope end and the loop code breaks.

here is a version that makes no assignments so is unaffected by the cell scope.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\mystrut}{\rule[-0.05\baselineskip]{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}}
\newcommand*{\mybox}[1]{\framebox{\mystrut #1}}
\newcommand{\derivblank}[1]{%
    \begin{align*}
    \xderivblank{#1}%
&=  \hspace{0.2cm}  \mybox{\underline{ \hspace{3cm}}}
    \end{align*}
}
\newcommand\xderivblank[1]{%
\ifnum#1=0 \else
        &= \hspace{0.2cm}\underline{\mystrut\hspace{3cm}}  \\
\xderivblank{\numexpr#1-1}\fi}


\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Derivation of 3 steps}
    Write your derivation below in 3 steps:
    \begin{align*}
    &= \hspace{0.2cm}\underline{\mystrut\hspace{3cm}}  \\
    &= \hspace{0.2cm}\underline{\mystrut\hspace{3cm}} \\
    &=  \hspace{0.2cm}  \mybox{\underline{ \hspace{3cm}}}
    \end{align*}
    
    \section*{Fails for arbitrary number of lines}
    Write your derivation below in $n$ steps:
    \derivblank{2}
\end{document}
```